# WSL with docker desktop

Tags: visual-studio-code, makefile, protocol-buffers, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have cloned [this](https://github.com/grafana/tempo) repo.

It makes use of 'make' for various operations, some of which don't work well(like one for generating go bindings for protos) in windows. So I decided to use WSL, and integrated WSL with VSC following [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl).

I am able to open project in WSL env from VSC. Now when I run command:

> make gen-proto

I see message:

> The command 'docker' could not be found in this WSL 2 distro. We
> recommend to activate the WSL integration in Docker Desktop settings.

But on my docker desktop I have wsl already configured.

[image]

What am I missing in my setup?

Comment: related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72483632/11107541